# .htaccess redirect all files/folders after www.website.com/

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Hi I am currently moving a site to new hosting, previously they had lots of folders/files in the document root which i have moved to another server i.e. www.website.com/foldera/test.zip or just www.website.com/file.mp3 now on hosting.website.com/file.mp3

because these url's are still in circulation i need to redirect all files to the new location so if the old link is clicked it will re-direct correctly.

They have a large amount of files/folders. Please advise on the best way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to the htaccess file in the document root of your old website:

```
Redirect 301 / http://hosting.website.com/
```

Or, if you'd rather use mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?website\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://hosting.website.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried both of these already, I have the first in place at the moment and some redirects work but mostly i receive 404 :Not Found

The requested URL /xyz/ was not found on this server.

Comment: Or I could approach from the other way and forward the site only, and leave the folders looking at the same location? @Jon-Lin